# Can't Solve IndexError, when comparing a row value with the next 2 rows

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to iterate through a specific column in a panda dataframe, in order to compare if there are consecutive declines in row value but I keep getting the index error: "single positional indexer is out-of-bounds", and TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'numpy.float64' and 'numpy.float64' respectively. Below is an extract from my actual data, and the code that gives the errors.

Give the sample data:

```
gdp = pd.DataFrame({"quater":['q1','q2','q3','q4','q1','q2','q3'], 
                'gdp_current':[243.1,246.3,250.1,260.3,266.2,272.9,279.5],
                'gdp_chained':[1934.5,1932.3,1930.3,1960.7,1989.5,2021.9,2033.2], 
                'identifier':['1947q1','1947q2','1947q3','1947q4','1948q1','1948q2','1948q3']
                })



for i in range(0,len(gdp)):
    if gdp.iloc[i, 1] > gdp.iloc[i+1, 1]:
        when = gdp.iloc[i, 2]
print(when)



for i in range(0,len(gdp)):
    if gdp.iloc[i, 1] > gdp.iloc[i+1, 1] & gdp.iloc[i, 1] > gdp.iloc[i+2, 1]:
        when = gdp.iloc[i, 2]
print(when)
```

I'll appreciate any help I can get. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know python but whenever you're using `i+1` as an index you'll go outside the bounds of the array when the loop is on the last iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `for` loop goes through entire DataFrame:

```
for i in range(0,len(gdp)):
```

and you are referring to `i+1`. That won't work when `i` is pointing to the last element.

You should either use `range(1,len(gdp))` and compare item `i-1` and item `i`,
or use `range(0,len(gdp)-1)` and compare item `i` and item `i+1`

This is a very common mistake, called [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

By the way, when your range starts at `0`, you don't need to specify that `0`. For example, `range(0,5)` is the same as `range(5)`

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly my problem. I ended up using `range(len(gdp) - 2)` and it worked

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help